# What happened to ManagedSpy?

Tags: managed, spy++

ManagedSpy is supposed to be the .NET equivalent of Spy++, but somehow the download page is now not availeble any more.

Anyone who knows why?

Anyone that knows a replacement?

--jeroen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can still download it [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/2/7/f279e71e-efb0-4155-873d-5554a0608523/ManagedSpy.exe), but the original website seems to be gone. There is however still an article in MSDN (from 2006) about [ManagedSpy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163617.aspx).

Answer (score 24):

I've cloned the original ManagedSpy source code and maintaining the code in modern environments (for example, ported it to .NET4).

See [project on GitHub](https://github.com/ForNeVeR/ManagedSpy).

Comment: Ideally, this should be the voted upon answer. Good job, @fornever

Comment: This is the real answer, I just verified that it worked on .NET 4.0  32-bits managed process.  Good job.

BTW, uispy.exe  and inspect.exe only shows a small subset of the properties, and it's readonly,  ManagedSpy is read-write

Comment: Any idea how to start spying on a window with it?! I've got just "no managed processes".

Comment: @PavelVlasov check your process' and ManagedSpy bitness (x86 vs x64). Also, if you run your process as admin, ManagedSpy should also be started as admin.

Answer (score 3):

I've cloned the ForNeVeR's ManagedSpy source code and changed a bit to support 64-bit process. see https://github.com/slimzhao/ManagedSpy

Comment: Why don't you send me a pull request? I'd gladly accept it :)

Comment: What's the authoritative github home?  I guess yours right.

Comment: For the record, I've incorporated these changes into my fork. Let's say that it's the main one, I'm trying to maintain it actively.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a newer equivlent tool? ManagedSpy fails completely on .NET 4.0 enabled machines because Native Images existing under \Windows\Assembly* and it tries loading those as .NET assemblies and fails.

Comment: I have not seen a replacement yet. Maybe you should ask this as a fresh question.

Comment: Figured as much, I will. Thanks.

Comment: For prosperity that question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860490/managed-version-of-spy-tool