# Managed version of Spy++ Tool?

Tags: .net, managed, spy++

Awhile ago, I needed a Spy++ like application for some .NET UI debugging. I found an old MSDN article with a sample that does things similarly, But that stopped working in newer .NET Framework versions.

Does anyone know of/wrote an application that mimics Spy++ behavior and works on Managed applications (rather, shows Managed events/properties) and works on newer .NET Frameworks, up to 4.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can recommend [UISpy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms727247.aspx), a spy utility which uses the [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx) framework to transparently spy on plain Win32 applications as well as [Windows Forms or [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx). It's a bit hard to find UISpy, but I downloaded just the executable itself from http://andrewtokeley.net/archive/2009/09/15/uispy-ndash-download-it-here.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd30h2yb(VS.80).aspx) - works great!

For .NET applications using Windows Forms and WPF, the application makes use of .NET reflection to display a huge number of properties for the objects.

Comment: It is no substitute for Managed Spy++ by a long shot.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Are you sure that's right in this case? The question asks for a tool that `shows Managed events/properties`. UISpy can do that.

Answer (score 2):

For winforms applications you still can use Spy++ as usual.

For WPF applications take a look to [this link](http://devintelligence.com/2007/05/a-spy-like-utility-for-wpf-applications/) . It talks about a tool called snoop. With this tool you can look into a WPF application.

As a side note, I haven't been able to make it work though

Comment: For the latest/best version of Snoop, go to http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/ - it does x86 and x64 in one executable and is much more stable.

Comment: +1 for Snoop. Make sure you run it as administrator when you launch it.

Comment: I had used WPF Inspector for a commercial project and it works great. Even snoop works good for me, but I'm more inclined towards WPF Inspector. You can find it here http://wpfinspector.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

The [Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8.1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/desktop/bg162891) includes [a tool named "Inspect Objects"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318521(v=vs.85).aspx) that I believe is intended as a Spy++ replacement.

Comment: I'm not so sure this does the same - Seems like it shows only automation relevant properties and only allows read only viewing.

Comment: @RanSagy Incorrect.  Also since when did Spy++ allow you to change things?

Comment: @MickyD i doubt i remember why and qhat i was thinking in 2011. thanks for the follow-up though.